# Google Apps Script to make copy of a spreadsheet and then populate the cells of the new spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to use a spreadsheet as template and then populate the cells in the newly created spreadsheet. Below is my code.

```
var sourceSheet = 'source spreadsheet ID'
var string = ["string"]
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");\
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderId');
var getFile = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSheet)
var newFile = (SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSheet).getName() + "_" + formattedDate)
getFile.makeCopy(newFile, folder);
var sheet = 'I need to know how to get 'newFile' getFileById()'
sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(string);
```

I need to know how to get the newly created file ID. Please help.

Comment: `getFile.makeCopy(newFile, folder);` will return a file object. You get details about this file if you catch this object. ie `var sheet = getFile.makeCopy(newFile, folder);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sudo bangbang wrote, [makeCopy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname-destination) returns a file object. Then you can [open](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openfile) that file as a spreadsheet:

```
var file = getFile.makeCopy(newFile, folder);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('some sheet name'); // or ss.getSheets()[0]; to get the first sheet
sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(string);
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped.